# Magento secret key admin login

Tags: magento, authentication, key, admin

I turned off the option to use the secret key in the Magento (1.7) admin URLs yesterday. Today when I try to log in it tries to use the secret key, but fails because I disabled it. The effect is that I can't get into the admin now because every login request fails. Can anyone give me the location of the setting in the database or give me another way out of the hole I dug for myself?

Comment: Hi @Erik If you have access to the DB of your Magento store, I am suggesting to look at the table "core_config_data" and to find a record with path = admin/security/use_form_key When you find this record set it's value to 1. Hope, that will help.

Comment: I reinstalled to fix the problem. But, its nice to know that if I goof up that again where to fix it. Thank You!

Comment: @ceckoslab You should add this as an answer, so that future visitors can find the solution.

Comment: Thanks @NeilAitken! I am doing it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't have access to Magento admin area, but you like to turn on the option to use the secret key in Magento you can try to execute SQL query over the DB of your Magento installation or to use web interface ( e.g. phpmyadmin ).

Basically you have to find a record where column **path** = **admin/security/use_form_key** in table **core_config_data** and to set it's value to **1**

In case you use phpmyadmin or similar software, just navigate to the table **core_config_data** find the desired record and change the value. It also will work if you delete the record, because if the record doesn't exist Magento will fetch the value of the xml configuration files and the value there is set to **1**

Also keep in mind, that some Magento installation use DB table prefixes and the table **core_config_data** may have different name e.g. **prefix_core_config_data**